# preg_match_all does not work on all php 7 version

Tags: php, php-7, preg-match-all

My dev and production env doesn't have the same exact version

My Dev env :  PHP 7.0.31-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)

My prod env : PHP 7.0.30 (cli)

For the exact same text this regular expression

```
preg_match_all('/%occupancies%((?!%endoccupancies%).|\n)*%endoccupancies%/', $text, $matches);
```

find matches in my dev env but not in prod

Code simple :

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b4541decc65089269f6aae0e4392dc9081c14615

Is there a way to fix this without upgrading my php version ?

Comment: Your assumption with the minor version being relevant is really farfetched. Look at the PCRE version for something meaningful. **After** you verified the $text input to be *identical* on both environments. That's a very cumbersome regex to achieve what you probably wanted.

Comment: [You shouldn't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5827005)

Comment: Yes, it is easy, use `'/%occupancies%[^%]*(?:%(?!endoccupancies%)[^%]*)*%endoccupancies%/'`

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern contains `((?!%endoccupancies%).|\n)*` alternation group that matches either a char other than a line break char that does not start a `%endoccupancies%` substring or a newline char (so, it does not match CRLF endings, e.g.). This group is quantified with `*` and that means that each char matched with this group is saved in the Group 1 memory slot, and is re-written each time a char is captured. That creates a huge overhead for the PCRE engine.

Re-write that part with `[^%]*(?:%(?!endoccupancies%)[^%]*)*` pattern. It matches:

- `[^%]*`  - 0+ chars other than `%`
- `(?:%(?!endoccupancies%)[^%]*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `%(?!endoccupancies%)` - a `%` not immediately followed with `endoccupancies%`
  - `[^%]*`  - 0+ chars other than `%`